# Ошибка в SQL-запросе

Tags: sqlite, sql

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку в SQL-запросе. Никогда с ними дела не имел, и вдруг волею судеб понадобилось.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "order": syntax error: , while compiling: CREATE TABLE ads (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT,badge TEXT,category TEXT,url TEXT,icon TEXT,vip INTEGER,order INTEGER,vip_order INTEGER,status INTEGER,created INTEGER,updated INTEGER);
```

Что не так рядом с order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE ads (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT,badge TEXT,category TEXT,url TEXT,icon TEXT,vip INTEGER,`order` INTEGER,vip_order INTEGER,`status` INTEGER,`created` INTEGER,`updated` INTEGER);
```

ORDER зарезервированное слово, надо ставить имена полей в кавычки

Comment: Да, спасибо, работает! А можно узнать, почему нужны кавычки? Вроде бы и без них всё создалось (ошибок не выдало, хотя напрямую пока посмотреть не могу).

Comment: Я же написал.

>ORDER зарезервированное слово

 Такие слова надо обрамлять кавычками, другие, не обязательно, но желательно, дабы быть уверенным что запрос будет корректным.